# iText7 508 Table Summary

Tags: itext7, section508

We are creating a large table using iText 7 we are almost fully 508 complaint however we are missing the table summary rule.

Is there a way to add the table summary at creation time using iText 7?

[image: Accessibility Summary]

[image: Tab Oder without Table Summary]

I have attached a picture of what I am looking for.
[image: Tab Order with Table Sumamry]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add AccessibilityProperties to the Table object itself. The Summary needs to be added through a PdfDictionary

```
PdfDictionary attr = new PdfDictionary();
attr.put(new PdfName("Summary"), new PdfString("Info about the table"));
table.getAccessibilityProperties().addAttributes(new PdfStructureAttributes(attr));
```

ApiDocs can be found [here](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/7.1.2/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/tagutils/AccessibilityProperties.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't set the table summary which is different than the alt text.   I have tried both setAlternateDescription and setActualText neither set the table summary. The only way I have found to create table summary is post pdf creation in adobe which does not fully meet our customers need.

Comment: @Ekalbs I updated the answer with the correct attribute

Comment: Sadly this didnt do it either.

I had to tweak the code since addAttribute didn’t take a dictionary.
 
PdfDictionary attr = new PdfDictionary();
attr.put(new PdfName("Summary"), new PdfString("Summary text"));
datatable.getAccessibilityProperties().addAttributes(new PdfStructureAttributes(attr));
 
This is the results. It appears it “breaks” the table. I have to retag as a table and then I can set the summary(in adobe).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Ekalbs I have tried your code, and it worked for me (iText 7.1.2). I've adapted Ross Frank's answer because not everyone reads the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution above, but unfortunately Adobe's Summary Accessebility Check failed.

According to the specification, the acceesibility properties' structure should be a bit different. One should use the next line:

```
tblContact.getAccessibilityProperties().addAttributes(new PdfStructureAttributes("Table").addTextAttribute("Summary","Table summary text" ));
```